# How can I replace a character with different patterns (HTML tags) in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like:

```
hello #this# is #some text string# text text
```

I want change it to:

```
hello <sometag>this</sometag> is <sometag>some text string</sometag> text text
```

That is, replace the first `#` with an HTML tag and the second `#` with the closing tag, and so on.  I am using Python; any body knows any regular expression or something other method?

Comment: Not sure what you want. Just the hashes removed or anything between hashes bolded? How? HTML?

Comment: edit: replace #this# inside html bold, #some text string# is inside another html bold etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to HTML bold everything separated by hashes surrounded by whitespace, you can do this:

```
import regex
regex = re.compile('(\s?)#(.*?)#(\s+)')
str = 'hello #this# is #some text string# text text'
str = re.sub(regex, '\\1<b>\\2</b>\\3', str)
```

If you want to match without space around the hashes, you change the relevant line to these:

```
regex = re.compile('#(.*?)#')
re.sub(regex, '<b>\\1</b>', str)
```

BUT this will only match paired hashes. In your example, it would result to `'<b>text</b>text text<b>text</b>text#text text'`

Comment: this works fine with space separated #. but how can match this #text#text text#text#text#text text

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the hashes (#) a simple replace will do the job:

```
 str=str.replace('#','')
```

Comment: He wants to replace the hashes with HTML tags; they weren't showing up because he didn't use code formatting.